# I am able to display custom link in left side dashboard but unable to make it has clicked in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard

How can I get the solutions for these I am able to display custom link in left side dashboard but unable to make it has clicked in magento 2, as not clicked when clicking on my link.

Comment: Can you describe, what you have try to do with code?